# Expo SQLite doesn't work for tables with Foreign Key

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I have a React Native project managed by expo and I am trying to work on an offline database so ended up going with the expo-sqlite package since everything else that is better (watermelondb, pouchdb, realm etc.) doesn't work with expo managed workflow. So very basic table creation is working fine, but whenever I am trying to add a foreign key it just says that the parent table can't be resolved. So in the following chunk of code, the error is `Unable to resolve table 'Profile'`.

[image]

Below is a good picture to illustrate what I am seeing on IntelliJ. So far I haven't found any way of selecting a Datasource since if you are developing with expo the very basic way (not specifically for android or iOS) then there's no way to choose the Datasource.

I know that you would also have to turn on PRAGMA Foreign Keys and I have done so as well first with `tx.executeSql` and finally what you see below (that's how it currently is).

[image]

I have also gone to Project Structure and tried out SQLite, GeneralSQL, and MySQL for SQL Dialects under Langauge and Framework.

I am launching the expo app on an iOS device if that makes any difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't anything to do with this specific table but another one similar to this one later down the file. Also disregard the red on table_name and column_id, since that is something not solvable with how IntelliJ IDEA is setup (at least with what I have come to figure out!)

So initially I had the code like the following. Notice how the foreign key is declared on line 4

[image]

After a whole lot of commenting and uncommenting chunks of code, I found out that this was the one that was causing the problem. So I found out in this [github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3726) that you can write transaction in the following way:

```
tx.executeSql("...", [], null, null)
//or
tx.executeSql("...", [], null, (tx, error) => {
  return true //rollback
})
```

And changing my code similary led me to the realization that, the

```
FOREIN KEY (column) REFRENCES PARENT_TABLE ( PARENT_TABLE_COLUMN )
```

has to be at the very last line otherwise, you will get errors such as `syntax error at created_at` (that was the error for me since created_at was right after the foreign key line)

Finally, I changed it to:

[image]

Bottom line is, instead of `tx.executeSql("...")` if you write out all the arguments and even pass a console log in the `error_callback` your life will become much better debugging what went wrong!